# Angular unit test results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a suite of unit tests for a moderately large Angular project, and am getting the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
    at AriaDescriber.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js.AriaDescriber._createMessagesContainer (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js:268:31)
    at AriaDescriber.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js.AriaDescriber._createMessageElement (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js:221:1)
    at AriaDescriber.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js.AriaDescriber.describe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js:142:1)
    at MatTooltip.set [as message] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/tooltip.es5.js:263:1)
    at updateProp (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22206:1)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21965:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23264:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23226:1)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23860:1)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23820:1)
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:896:1
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:1)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:698:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:317:1)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422:1)
    at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:601:1)
```

This happens on 2 of the tests, but doesn't happen on those tests when they are run by themselves (ie, when using `fdescribe` instead of `describe`).

Despite what appears in the call stack, I am not using `MatToolTip` or `removeChild` in the code or the tests.  The problem seems like it is occurring in the test framework.  At this point I don't know what else to try.  Has anyone seen this before or have any thoughts about where to look?

Comment: Hi piccy, do you have any fix for this issue...? I am also having same issue and its happening randomly on different specs. Is their any fix for it..?

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM is missing a parent, probably mis-spelled. These are hard to locate oftentimes especially when the linter is not locating a file location. Download the ReactJS DEV browser add-on it helps in these situations

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in angular spec.
i found out that `CdkTableModule` was missing in module imports.

Comment: Hi @Apoorv, do you have any fix for this issue...? I am also having same issue and its happening randomly on different specs. Is their any fix for it..?